# PostGreSQL - Entity insert - Dduplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity

I'm having this erro when trying to insert a new record on database:

"Duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

This is my insert method:

```
            using ( DataContext objDB = new DataContext() )
            {
                objDB.Set<T>().Add( item );
                objDB.Entry( item ).State = EntityState.Added;
                objDB.SaveChanges();
                return item;
            }
```

The table that I'm trying to insert is like this in EDMX modeling:

```
<EntityType Name="tb_functionality">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="id" Type="int4" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="name" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

And the object that I'm trying to insert ('item') is like this on code:

ID=0
Name='Test'

What is wrong on my code? This works perfect when I'm using SQL Server, so in PostGre I have to chance anything on my model or insert method?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you definig the id on this object constructor?

Comment: Yes, it is defined. And its value is been set to 0, since the ID value is not modified.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but when you use `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` you are telling hibernate to genarate the id, try don't set the id in the constructor.

Comment: I'll have to modify my view model or create another one for insert because the same view model is used to fill the fields on GridView, for example. I thought that could have any property to disable the PK. I'll try it here, thanks for the answer.

Comment: The StoreGeneratedPattern property was inserted by the EDMX when I generated it. I'll try without it.